# Function to make simple 1-path SVG from complicated SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I have function (I can't change it), that creates SVG string from .dxf. It works fine, but I can't fill it. For example, I have:

```
<svg id="svgView" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="-225.75000000000014 -1235.8500000000001 451.5000000000003 367.7000000000004" width="100%" height="100%">
<g stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5%" fill="none" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,0)">
  <g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="-150" cy="1117" r="11.5"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="-150" cy="1077" r="11.5"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="-150" cy="977" r="6"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="-50" cy="977" r="6"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="50" cy="977" r="6"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="150" cy="977" r="6"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="-150" cy="1017" r="11.5"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="-50" cy="1017" r="11.5"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="50" cy="1017" r="11.5"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="150" cy="1017" r="11.5"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="-207" cy="1169" r="2"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="-138" cy="1169" r="2"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="-69" cy="1169" r="2"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="0" cy="1169" r="2"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="69" cy="1169" r="2"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="138" cy="1169" r="2"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="207" cy="1169" r="2"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="-207" cy="1091" r="2"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="-207" cy="1013" r="2"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="-207" cy="935" r="2"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="207" cy="935" r="2"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="138" cy="935" r="2"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="69" cy="935" r="2"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="0" cy="935" r="2"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="-69" cy="935" r="2"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="-138" cy="935" r="2"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="207" cy="1013" r="2"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<circle cx="207" cy="1091" r="2"></circle>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<path d="M207,1177L-207,1177"></path>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<path d="M -207 1177 A 8 8 0 0 1 -215 1169"></path>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<path d="M-215,1169L-215,935"></path>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<path d="M -215 935 A 8 8 0 0 1 -207 927"></path>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<path d="M-207,927L207,927"></path>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<path d="M 207 927 A 8 8 0 0 1 215 935"></path>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<path d="M215,935L215,1169"></path>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<path d="M 215 1169 A 8 8 0 0 1 207 1177"></path>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<path d="M-46.25,1143.25L46.25,1143.25"></path>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<path d="M46.25,1143.25L46.25,1050.75"></path>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<path d="M46.25,1050.75L-46.25,1050.75"></path>
</g>
<g stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<path d="M-46.25,1050.75L-46.25,1143.25"></path>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

And here is string, that I want to receive:

```
<svg id="svgView" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="-225.75000000000014 -1235.8500000000001 451.5000000000003 367.7000000000004" width="100%" height="100%">
  <g stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5%" fill="grey" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,0)">
  <path d="
            M -161.5, 1117
            a 11.5,11.5 0 1,0 23,0
            a 11.5,11.5 0 1,0 -23,0

            M -161.5, 1077
            a 11.5,11.5 0 1,0 23,0
            a 11.5,11.5 0 1,0 -23,0

            M -156, 977
            a 6,6 0 1,0 12,0
            a 6,6 0 1,0 -12,0

            M -56, 977
            a 6,6 0 1,0 12,0
            a 6,6 0 1,0 -12,0

            M 44, 977
            a 6,6 0 1,0 12,0
            a 6,6 0 1,0 -12,0

            M 144, 977
            a 6,6 0 1,0 12,0
            a 6,6 0 1,0 -12,0

            M -161.5, 1017
            a 11.5,11.5 0 1,0 23,0
            a 11.5,11.5 0 1,0 -23,0

            M -61.5, 1017
            a 11.5,11.5 0 1,0 23,0
            a 11.5,11.5 0 1,0 -23,0

            M 38.5, 1017
            a 11.5,11.5 0 1,0 23,0
            a 11.5,11.5 0 1,0 -23,0

            M 138.5, 1017
            a 11.5,11.5 0 1,0 23,0
            a 11.5,11.5 0 1,0 -23,0

            M -209, 1169
            a 2,2 0 1,0 4,0
            a 2,2 0 1,0 -4,0

            M -140, 1169
            a 2,2 0 1,0 4,0
            a 2,2 0 1,0 -4,0

            M -71, 1169
            a 2,2 0 1,0 4,0
            a 2,2 0 1,0 -4,0

            M -2, 1169
            a 2,2 0 1,0 4,0
            a 2,2 0 1,0 -4,0

            M 67, 1169
            a 2,2 0 1,0 4,0
            a 2,2 0 1,0 -4,0

            M 136, 1169
            a 2,2 0 1,0 4,0
            a 2,2 0 1,0 -4,0

            M 205, 1169
            a 2,2 0 1,0 4,0
            a 2,2 0 1,0 -4,0

            M -209, 1091
            a 2,2 0 1,0 4,0
            a 2,2 0 1,0 -4,0

            M -209, 1013
            a 2,2 0 1,0 4,0
            a 2,2 0 1,0 -4,0

            M -209, 935
            a 2,2 0 1,0 4,0
            a 2,2 0 1,0 -4,0

            M 205, 935
            a 2,2 0 1,0 4,0
            a 2,2 0 1,0 -4,0

            M 136, 935
            a 2,2 0 1,0 4,0
            a 2,2 0 1,0 -4,0

            M 67, 935
            a 2,2 0 1,0 4,0
            a 2,2 0 1,0 -4,0

            M -2, 935
            a 2,2 0 1,0 4,0
            a 2,2 0 1,0 -4,0

            M -71, 935
            a 2,2 0 1,0 4,0
            a 2,2 0 1,0 -4,0

            M -140, 935
            a 2,2 0 1,0 4,0
            a 2,2 0 1,0 -4,0

            M 205, 1013
            a 2,2 0 1,0 4,0
            a 2,2 0 1,0 -4,0

            M 205, 1091
            a 2,2 0 1,0 4,0
            a 2,2 0 1,0 -4,0

            M207,1177L-207,1177
            A 8 8 0 0 1 -215 1169
            L-215,935
            A 8 8 0 0 1 -207 927
            L207,927
            A 8 8 0 0 1 215 935
            L215,1169
            A 8 8 0 0 1 207 1177
            M-46.25,1143.25L46.25,1143.25
            L46.25,1050.75
            L-46.25,1050.75
            L-46.25,1143.25
            "></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

What is the simplest way to do that in function?
P.S. for closed paths I need to cut **M x,y** if previous path had same coordinates at the end, for circles i use this formula: 
**M (CX - R), CY
      a R,R 0 1,0 (R * 2),0
      a R,R 0 1,0 -(R * 2),0**

Comment: You can't fill it? What does that mean?

Comment: i need to change background color of drawing(so i need to ignore holes in drawing) and fill attribute is the easiest way to do that, but it does not work if pathes are not closed (1st code)